# Counting and displaying distinct integers from user

Tags: java, loops

I have created a code that asks the user to input 10 numbers that must be negative and when they aren't, the user is forced to input again and then add up the sum of the 10 negative numbers as seen below. What I am trying to do now is to find distinct integers (how many there are and display the amount as well as list what they are). It is my understanding that distinct integers are just numbers that haven't been added already. For example, if `-1,-2,-3,-3,-9,-1,-7,-7,-1,-3` were entered then the amount of distinct integers would be 5 and they would be `-1,-2,-3,-7,-9`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class distinctint {
    double counter;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public double go() {
        int a;
        int n;
        counter = 7;

        while (counter != 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            if(newInteger < 0) {
                int newInteger = scan.nextInt()
                newint += newInteger;
                dial = dial - 1;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println("sum=" + newint);
    }
}
```

This issue I am having is trying to find a way to implement that into what I have. I am pretty sure that I will need an array of some sorts that will hold all of the distinct integers within it, but I'm not really sure where to begin. Would something like this make sense?

```
numbers[] distinctnumbers;
```

Comment: Have you learned about `TreeSet`?

Comment: You can insert the numbers into a set and then just print out the set at the end.

Comment: I don't know anything about sets at all. I'd rather use an array of some sort because that is what I'm more used to seeing

Comment: Today is the day for you to learn about Sets.  It will be much easier than using arrays.

Comment: well it seems like everybody is "set" on this :) anyone care to elaborate?

Comment: It would help you if you didn't use two different names for each variable, or reference variables before they've been set to anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that the `add` method of the `Set` interface returns `true` if the element you're adding is new to the set, and `false` if it was already in the set.

I would do something like this.  I've left out all your validation and looping, because you obviously know how to do this already.

```
// Before your loop

Set<Integer> numbersIveAdded = new HashSet<>();
int total = 0;



// Inside your loop

int numberEntered = scan.nextInt();
boolean thisIntegerIsNew = numbersIveAdded.add(numberEntered);
if (thisIntegerIsNew) {
    total += numberEntered;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help and all but can you help explain with arrays? This whole set thing isn't working for me

Comment: I've actually decided to go with this way. Where exactly in and out of the loop do they go because i am getting syntax errors where i am putting them

Comment: offtopic: Just saw *Text deleted due to general dizziness by respondent.* You made my day sir, upvoting just for that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned before, `Set` is still the most optimal way to do this. But if you have a requirement to use only `Arrays`, you can do the following.

```
//outside while loop
int[] array = new int[10];

//inside the while loop
int newInteger = scan.nextInt();
if(newInteger >= 0) 
{
    System.out.println("Must be negative integer, please try again");
}
else if (checkIfAlreadyPresent(array, newInteger)) {
    System.out.println("Integer already present, please enter a distinct one.");
} else {
    n+=newInteger;
    counter = counter - 1;
    a=a+newInteger; 
}

//O(n) worst case vs O(1) for Set
public boolean checkIfIntegerAlreadyPresent(int[] array, int inputInteger) {
    for(int a:array) {
        if(a==inputInteger)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```